# Running QTP Tests on Internet Explorer 64 bit

Tags: internet-explorer-9, 64-bit, qtp

I want to execute QTP tests on Internet Explorer 9 64 bit version.
We are using QTP 11 on Windows Server 2008 R2
We are using QTP's automation object model to run the tests using the below statement

qtApp.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").Browser = "IE"

I need to know how can I run my scripts against the 64 bit Internet Explorer 9?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE".....

http://relevantcodes.com/qtp-11-0-patches/

Support for 64-bit IE Browsers
This patch enables creating and running steps on 64-bit Internet Explorer browsers. Note:
Before installing this patch, you must install the QTP_00699 patch.
This patch does not provide 64-bit support for other Web-based environments, for example .NET WebForms, ActiveX, Siebel, PeopleSoft, Web-based SAP and so on.
**The patch does not support selecting the 64-bit Internet Explorer browser in the Record and Run Settings dialog box. Workaround: Either use the SystemUtil.Run method to open the browser or open it manually.**
This patch does not provide support for ViewLink test objects in Internet Explorer 9 on 64-bit operating systems.